# Server Sent Events in Cloud Code

Tags: node.js, parse-platform

I'm trying to implement a simple SSE in Cloud Code.

Here's my Express route to open the connection:

```
app.get('/call', function(req, res) {

  // let request last as long as possible
  req.socket.setTimeout(30000);

  //send headers for event-stream connection
  res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive'
  });

  res.write('\n');

  // The 'close' event is fired when a user closes their browser window.
  req.on("close", function() {

  });
});
```

I've also made sure to include:

```
var http = require('http');
```

Problem is, I'm getting this error:

```
  I2014-06-28T19:09:50.500Z] TypeError: Object function () {
    throw Error('IncomingMessage.socket not supported');
  } has no method 'setTimeout'
    at app.js:129:14
    at callbacks (express_router.js:161:37)
    at param (express_router.js:135:11)
    at pass (express_router.js:142:5)
    at Router._dispatch (express_router.js:170:5)
    at Object.router (express_router.js:33:10)
    at next (connect_proto.js:240:15)
    at Object.handle (app.js:88:7)
    at next (connect_proto.js:240:15)
    at Object.parseExpressCookieSession [as handle] (parse-express-cookie-session.js:315:7)
```

I've also tried just:

```
req.setTimeout(30000);
```

But get a similar error.

I read something about how `setTimeout` isn't implement until a later version of node. Could this be the issue? I couldn't find what version of node Parse is running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse Cloud Code does not support `setTimeout()`. They don't seem to actually mention this anywhere in the documentation, but they have stated it numerous times in the old forums and in other questions here.

Comment: I've just decided to try to setup my own node server. I've run into too many restrictions trying to use Cloud Code with what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using PubNub.com in conjunction with parse.com to get a realtime experience.

Comment: Any details on how to use it?

Comment: This link will help you to get there http://www.pubnub.com/blog/realtime-collaboration-sync-parse-api-pubnub/

Comment: Can you give a code example how you can use it to solve the problem in the question?

Answer (score -1):

I have found the answer in this [Google Group Discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/parse-developers/T-7dkGx1BCQ) by Hector Ramos from Parse:

> `setTimeout()` is not available in Cloud Code, but you can use `process.nextTick()` instead. You can see an example in Fosco's queuing module [Parse-Resque](https://github.com/gfosco/parse-resque/blob/master/parse-rita.js).